# Kubernetes NodeAffinity Confusion

Tags: kubernetes

New to kubernetes and trying to digest the concept of NodeAffinity. The instructions provided at the K8s doc [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/) has the following on NodeAffinity :-

- If you specify multiple matchExpressions associated with a single nodeSelectorTerms, then the Pod can be scheduled onto a node only if all the matchExpressions are satisfied.

trying to understand how the multiple matchExpression work and so I created the following pod definition
[image]

As you can see I have multiple match expression and only one satisfies the criteria. When I create the pod using the above definition, Scheduler always creates the pod on the matching node which based on my understanding from the documentation it should not. Can someone please provide some guidance here?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Just include the text itself in your question, formatted as a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the documentation was just wrong at the time. Now it describes the correct behavior.

```
If you specify multiple terms in nodeSelectorTerms associated with
nodeAffinity types, then the Pod can be scheduled onto a node if one of the
specified terms can be satisfied (terms are ORed).

If you specify multiple expressions in a single matchExpressions field
associated with a term in nodeSelectorTerms, then the Pod can be scheduled
onto a node only if all the expressions are satisfied (expressions are
ANDed).
```